# How can I download apps on the Onda tablet?

Tags: installation, onda-tablet

How can I download apps on the Onda tablet?

It is Android-enabled, but it doesn't have internet.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise? Doesn't it even have WiFi? No SDCard either? I never heard of that tablet before, so please forgive me not knowing those details ;)

Comment: @Izzy - see [this](http://www.onda-tablet.com/)... looks to be some cheap chinese tablet... :\ Either the OP is uncertain in how to enable Wifi or there is no internet connectivity in the OP's location?

Comment: According to t0mm3b's link, there are multiple different Onda-tablets. Grainne, could you pick the one you have and add the corresponding link? It looks like they support WiFi and even WiFi direct. So if you have a WiFi access point, you could use the Internet that way.